# How to provide a default loader for image lazy load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using below library for lazy loading the code is as :

```
          angular.module('me-lazyload', [])
.directive('lazySrc', ['$window', '$document', function($window, $document){
var doc = $document[0],
    body = doc.body,
    win = $window,
    $win = angular.element(win),
    uid = 0,
    elements = {};

function getUid(el){
    var __uid = el.data("__uid");
    if (! __uid) {
        el.data("__uid", (__uid = '' + ++uid));
    }
    return __uid;
}

function getWindowOffset(){
    var t,
        pageXOffset = (typeof win.pageXOffset == 'number') ? win.pageXOffset : (((t = doc.documentElement) || (t = body.parentNode)) && typeof t.scrollLeft == 'number' ? t : body).scrollLeft,
        pageYOffset = (typeof win.pageYOffset == 'number') ? win.pageYOffset : (((t = doc.documentElement) || (t = body.parentNode)) && typeof t.scrollTop == 'number' ? t : body).scrollTop;
    return {
        offsetX: pageXOffset,
        offsetY: pageYOffset
    };
}

function isVisible(iElement){
    var elem = iElement[0],
        elemRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),
        windowOffset = getWindowOffset(),
        winOffsetX = windowOffset.offsetX,
        winOffsetY = windowOffset.offsetY,
        elemWidth = elemRect.width || elem.width,
        elemHeight = elemRect.height || elem.height,
        elemOffsetX = elemRect.left + winOffsetX,
        elemOffsetY = elemRect.top + winOffsetY,
        viewWidth = Math.max(doc.documentElement.clientWidth, win.innerWidth || 0),
        viewHeight = Math.max(doc.documentElement.clientHeight, win.innerHeight || 0),
        xVisible,
        yVisible;

    if(elemOffsetY <= winOffsetY){
        if(elemOffsetY + elemHeight >= winOffsetY){
            yVisible = true;
        }
    }else if(elemOffsetY >= winOffsetY){
        if(elemOffsetY <= winOffsetY + viewHeight){
            yVisible = true;
        }
    }

    if(elemOffsetX <= winOffsetX){
        if(elemOffsetX + elemWidth >= winOffsetX){
            xVisible = true;
        }
    }else if(elemOffsetX >= winOffsetX){
        if(elemOffsetX <= winOffsetX + viewWidth){
            xVisible = true;
        }
    }

    return xVisible && yVisible;
};

function checkImage(){
    angular.forEach(elements, function(obj, key) {
        var iElement = obj.iElement,
            $scope = obj.$scope;
        if(isVisible(iElement)){
          iElement.attr('src', $scope.lazySrc);
        }
    });
}

$win.bind('scroll', checkImage);
$win.bind('resize', checkImage);

function onLoad(){
    var $el = angular.element(this),
        uid = getUid($el);

    $el.css('opacity', 1);

    if(elements.hasOwnProperty(uid)){
        delete elements[uid];
    }
}

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        lazySrc: '@',
        animateVisible: '@',
        animateSpeed: '@'
    },
    link: function($scope, iElement){
        iElement.bind('load', onLoad);

        $scope.$watch('lazySrc', function(){
            var speed = "1s";
            if ($scope.animateSpeed != null) {
                speed = $scope.animateSpeed;
            }
            if(isVisible(iElement)){
                if ($scope.animateVisible) {
                    iElement.css({
                        'opacity': 0,
                        '-webkit-transition': 'opacity ' + speed,
                        'transition': 'opacity ' + speed
                    });
                }
                iElement.attr('src', $scope.lazySrc);
            }else{
                var uid = getUid(iElement);
                iElement.css({
                    'opacity': 0,
                    '-webkit-transition': 'opacity ' + speed,
                    'transition': 'opacity ' + speed
                });
                elements[uid] = {
                    iElement: iElement,
                    $scope: $scope
                };
            }
        });

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
            iElement.unbind('load');
            var uid = getUid(iElement);
            if(elements.hasOwnProperty(uid)){
                delete elements[uid];
            }
        });
    }
};
```

}]);
works good for vertical scroll but when i go for horizontal scroll the images doesn't load until i scroll vertically and i the default image also doesn't work for this.

for more reference go to https://github.com/Treri/me-lazyload

regards

Comment: Is this [bug](https://github.com/Treri/me-lazyload/issues/7) related?

Comment: yes. there are 2 bugs one horizontal scroll and another default loader

Comment: have you tried using ng-src="image src goes here"?  instead of normal src=""

Comment: yes i have .. it doesn't work here